# Export to pdf SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I've some questions regarding SSRS:

I want to create Account Statements of each client

1. Is it possible in SSRS to do so that I will pass AccountID as a parameter for each client, and it will form and save pdf files in C drive for each AccountID. How can I automate that?
2. I've e-mail table of each client. Is it possible to send account statements to clients according to this e-mail list? In other words, can I query recipients of account statements and send them an e-mail with their account statements.

Thanks

Comment: Is this one-time thing or you plan to send PDFs on a regular basis? I'm thinking of a powershell script that, according to your list of AccountID <-> Email pairs, creates URL for SSRS (supplies parameter and adds &rs:Format=PDF) and sends an email.

Comment: I should do this once a month. Is that possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this on a regular basis, you need to utilize a feature called Data Driven Subscription.

Basically, it looks at a table(Parameter, EmailAddress) in a SQL Server.

For instance, let's say you have:

> ID - Name     ------ Parameter ---------------- Email
>
> 1 - SalesGuy1 - 123123123 - SalesGuy1@emailaddress.com
>
> 2 - SalesGuy2 - 111111111 - SalesGuy2@emailaddress.com
>
> 3 - SalesGuy3 - 222222222 - SalesGuy3@emailaddress.com

It then, according to this table, executes with a parameter and sends report to appropriate user.

There is no short way of describing step-by-step, so please have a look at a well-written Microsoft KB article: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237461%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

There is also slightly newer version (but basically the same content): 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169673.aspx

Note: You cannot use Shared Data source with data driven subscription. You have to configure email settings inside SSRS for this to work.

Comment: Seems like exactly what I want, I'll have deep look at it. Thanks. One more question, is it possible to save this reports in hard drive? For instance, 'SalesGuy1.doc, SalesGuy2.doc and so on' Thanks once more

Comment: Yes. There is combobox that allows you to choose to send by email or to store it in a folder.